# What kind of problems for not forwarding universal reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, universal-reference

As far as I know, in C++11, universal reference should always be used with `std::forward`, but I am not sure of what kind of problem can occur if `std::forward` is not used.

```
template <T>
void f(T&& x);
{
    // What if x is used without std::forward<T>(x) ?
}
```

Could you provide some illustrations of problems that could occur in this situation ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is **no such rule** to **always** use `std::forward` with *universal references*. On the contrary, it can be dangerous to use `std::forward` all over the place in functions with *universal references*. Take a look at the following example:

```
template <typename T>
auto make_pair(T&& t)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<T>(t)); // BAD
}
```

If you call this function with `make_pair(std::string{"foobar"})`, the result is counter-intuitive, because you move from the same object twice.

---

**Update:** Here is another example to show, that it really makes sense to use *universal references* without *perfect forwarding*:

```
template <typename Range, typename Action>
void foreach(Range&& range, Action&& action)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    for (auto p = begin(range), q = end(range); p != q; ++p) {
        action(*p);
    }
}
```

- It's good that *range* is a *universal reference*, so that the caller can use *foreach* with a temporary container and an action, that's calls a *non-const* member function on the elements.
- It's good that *action* is a *universal reference*, so that the caller can pass a *mutable lambda expression* as action.
- And it would be wrong to use `std::forward` for *range* or for *action*.

Comment: Very good point but it doesn't clearly answer the question "what kind of problem can occur if std::forward is not used?"

Comment: +1, but why would it be wrong to use `std::forward` for `action`? I just read this: [Why use a perfectly forwarded value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24779910/873025), and it seems you may throw away an optimization opportunity if not preserving the r-valueness.

Comment: @Snps: In contrast to `std::apply`, the above code contains a loop. Depending on the type of `Action`, `std::forward<Action>(action)` can be the same as `std::move(action)`. That means with `std::forward` you would potentially change the function object `action` in the first iteration and causing strange behaviour for all remaining iterations.

Comment: @nosid Duh, the loop (how could I miss that). Makes sense now, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: The first example is pretty bad. If the purpose is to `make_tuple(t, t)`, then `T&&` probably should not be used in the first place—`const T&` would be better.

Answer (score 10):

Let's say `f` is called like this:

```
f(someType{});
```

If the body of `f` performs some kind of operation on `x`

```
foo(x);
```

and there are two overloads for `foo`

```
void foo(someType const&);

void foo(someType&&);
```

without using `std::forward`, as `x` is an lvalue the following overload is called

```
void foo(someType const&);
```

which might cost you a potential optimization.

Using

```
foo(std::forward<T>(x));
```

makes sure the correct overload of `foo` is selected.

Answer (score 6):

Things with a name are lvalues. That means that in the function body, `t` is an lvalue. It doesn't matter if the universal reference ends up as an lvalue reference or as an rvalue reference. If it's named, it's an lvalue.

If you thus pass that argument along directly, you will be passing an lvalue.

In a situation where you want to just pass along an opaque argument to another function, you want to pass it exactly as-is. If it was an lvalue, you want to pass it as an lvalue; if it was an rvalue you want to pass an rvalue. As explained, passing it directly passes it as an lvalue *always*. `forward` does the magic needed to pass it as the right kind of value,

Code that always passes an lvalue will likely suffer from a performance perspective but I would say that you can ignore that when thinking about this particular issue. There is a more pressing concern for not always passing an lvalue: while copying some types may be expensive, some other types cannot be copied *at all*, like `std::unique_ptr`. For those types preserving rvalueness when forwarding is not a matter of performance but of getting your code to even compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should not forward a variable more than once.