# Why use a perfectly forwarded value (a functor)?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, c++14

C++11 (and C++14) introduces additional language constructs and improvements that target generic programming. These include features such as;

- R-value references
- Reference collapsing
- Perfect forwarding
- Move semantics, variadic templates and more

I was browsing an earlier [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) of the [C++14 specification](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) (now with updated text) and the code in an example in §20.5.1, *Compile-time integer sequences*, that I found interesting and peculiar.

```
template<class F, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, index_sequence<I...>) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}

template<class F, class Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t) {
  using Indices = make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>;
  return apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t), Indices());
}
```

Online here [[intseq.general]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/intseq.general#2).

**Question**

- Why was the function `f` in `apply_impl` being forwarded, i.e. why `std::forward<F>(f)(std::get...`?
- Why not just apply the function as `f(std::get...`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### In Brief...

The TL;DR, you want to preserve the [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) (r-value/l-value nature) of the functor because this can affect the [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), in particular the [ref-qualified members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions).

### Function definition reduction

To focus on the issue of the function being forwarded, I've reduced the sample (and made it compile with a C++11 compiler) to;

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto apply_impl(F&& func, Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::forward<F>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
  return std::forward<F>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And we create a second form, where we replace the `std::forward(func)` with just `func`;

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto apply_impl_2(F&& func, Args&&... args) -> decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
  return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

### Sample evaluation

Evaluating some empirical evidence of how this behaves (with conforming compilers) is a neat starting point for evaluating why the code example was written as such. Hence, in addition we will define a general functor;

```
struct Functor1 {
  int operator()(int id) const
  {
    std::cout << "Functor1 ... " << id << std::endl;
    return id;
  }
};
```

**Initial sample**

Run some sample code;

```
int main()
{
  Functor1 func1;
  apply_impl_2(func1, 1);
  apply_impl_2(Functor1(), 2);
  apply_impl(func1, 3);
  apply_impl(Functor1(), 4);
}
```

And the output is as expected, independent of whether an r-value is used `Functor1()` or an l-value `func` when making the call to `apply_impl` and `apply_impl_2` the overloaded call operator is called. It is called for both r-values and l-values. Under C++03, this was all you got, you could not overload member methods based on the "r-value-ness" or "l-value-ness" of the object.

> Functor1 ... 1
> Functor1 ... 2
> Functor1 ... 3
> Functor1 ... 4

**Ref-qualified samples**

We now need to overload that call operator to stretch this a little further...

```
struct Functor2 {
  int operator()(int id) const &
  {
    std::cout << "Functor2 &... " << id << std::endl;
    return id;
  }
  int operator()(int id) &&
  {
    std::cout << "Functor2 &&... " << id << std::endl;
    return id;
  }
};
```

We run another sample set;

```
int main()
{
  Functor2 func2;
  apply_impl_2(func2, 5);
  apply_impl_2(Functor2(), 6);
  apply_impl(func2, 7);
  apply_impl(Functor2(), 8);
}
```

And the output is;

> Functor2 &... 5
> Functor2 &... 6
> Functor2 &... 7
> Functor2 &&... 8

**Discussion**

In the case of `apply_impl_2` (`id` 5 and 6), the output is not as may have been initially been expected. In both cases, the l-value qualified `operator()` is called (the r-value is not called at all). It may have been expected that since `Functor2()`, an r-value, is used to call `apply_impl_2` the r-value qualified `operator()` would have been called. The `func`, as a named parameter to `apply_impl_2`, is an r-value reference, but since it is named, it is itself an l-value. Hence the l-value qualified `operator()(int) const&` is called in both the case of the l-value `func2` being the argument and the r-value `Functor2()` being used as the argument.

In the case of `apply_impl` (`id` 7 and 8) the `std::forward<F>(func)` *maintains or preserves* the r-value/l-value nature of the argument provided for `func`. Hence the l-value qualified `operator()(int) const&` is called with the l-value `func2` used as the argument and the r-value qualified `operator()(int)&&` when the r-value `Functor2()` is used as the argument. This behaviour is what would have been expected.

### Conclusions

**The use of `std::forward`, via perfect forwarding, ensures that we *preserve the r-value/l-value nature* of the original argument for `func`. It preserves their [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).**

It is required, `std::forward` can and should be used for more than just *forwarding* arguments to functions, but also when the use of an argument is required where the *r-value/l-value nature must be preserved*. Note; there are situations where the r-value/l-value cannot or should not be preserved, in these situations `std::forward` should not be used (see the converse below).

There are many examples popping up that inadvertently lose the r-value/l-value nature of the arguments via a seemingly innocent use of an r-value reference.

It has always been hard to write well defined and sound generic code. With the introduction of r-value references, and reference collapsing in particular, it has become possible to write better generic code, more concisely, but we need to be ever more aware of what the original nature of the arguments provided are and make sure that they are maintained when we use them in the generic code we write.

Full sample code can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1db78eeb0186e30d)

### Corollary and converse

- A corollary of the question would be; given reference collapsing in a templated function, how is the r-value/l-value nature of the argument maintained? The answer - use `std::forward<T>(t)`.
- Converse; does `std::forward` solve all your "universal reference" problems? No it doesn't, there are cases where it [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23286468/3747990), such as forwarding the value more than once.

---

### Brief background to perfect forwarding

Perfect forwarding may be unfamiliar to some, so what is *perfect forwarding*?

In brief, perfect forwarding is there to ensure that the argument provided to a function is forwarded (passed) to another function with the same value category (basically r-value vs. l-value) as [originally provided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). It is typically used with template functions where [reference collapsing](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) may have taken place.

Scott Meyers gives the following pseudo code in his [Going Native 2013 presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler) to explain the workings of `std::forward` (at approximately the 20 minute mark);

```
template <typename T>
T&& forward(T&& param) { // T&& here is formulated to disallow type deduction
  if (is_lvalue_reference<T>::value) {
    return param; // return type T&& collapses to T& in this case
  }
  else {
    return move(param);
  }
}
```

Perfect forwarding depends on a handful of fundamental language constructs new to C++11 that form the bases for much of what we now see in generic programming:

- Reference collapsing
- Rvalue references
- Move semantics

The use of `std::forward` is currently intended in the formulaic `std::forward<T>`, understanding how `std::forward` works helps understand why this is such, and also aids in identifying non-idiomatic or incorrect use of rvalues, reference collapsing and ilk.

Thomas Becker provides a nice, but dense write up on the perfect forwarding [problem](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html) and [solution](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html).

### What are ref-qualifiers?

The ref-qualifiers (lvalue ref-qualifier `&` and rvalue ref-qualifier `&&`) are similar to the cv-qualifiers in that they (the [ref-qualified members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions)) are used during [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) to determine which method to call. They behave as you would expect them to; the `&` applies to lvalues and `&&` to rvalues. **Note:** Unlike cv-qualification, `*this` remains an l-value expression.

Comment: Today I discover ref-qualified methods. My mind has been blown.

Comment: Additional link to [Advantages of forward](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/3747990) on SO

Answer (score 13):

Here is a practical example.

```
struct concat {
  std::vector<int> state;
  std::vector<int> const& operator()(int x)&{
    state.push_back(x);
    return state;
  }
  std::vector<int> operator()(int x)&&{
    state.push_back(x);
    return std::move(state);
  }
  std::vector<int> const& operator()()&{ return state; }
  std::vector<int> operator()()&&{ return std::move(state); }
};
```

This function object takes an `x`, and concatenates it to an internal `std::vector`.  It then returns that `std::vector`.

If evaluated in an rvalue context it `move`s to a temporary, otherwise it returns a `const&` to the internal vector.

Now we call `apply`:

```
auto result = apply( concat{}, std::make_tuple(2) );
```

because we carefully forwarded our function object, only 1 `std::vector` buffer is allocated.  It is simply moved out to `result`.

Without the careful forwarding, we end up creating an internal `std::vector`, and we copy it to `result`, then discard the internal `std::vector`.

Because the `operator()&&` knows that the function object should be treated as a rvalue about to be destroyed, it can rip the guts out of the function object while doing its operation.  The `operator()&` cannot do this.

Careful use of perfect forwarding of function objects enables this optimization.

Note, however, that there is very little use of this technique "in the wild" at this point.  Rvalue qualified overloading is obscure, and doing so to `operator()` moreso.

I could easily see future versions of C++ automatically using the rvalue state of a lambda to implicitly `move` its captured-by-value data in certain contexts, however.